# TypeScript errors while trying to assign properties from one object to another

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

My code:

```
const state = { activeRequests: 0, test: true };
type state = typeof state;
type pState = Partial<state>;
type stateKeys = keyof state; // "activeRequests" | "test"
...
set: (state: state, p: pState) => Object.keys(p).forEach(k => (state[k] = p[k]))
```

Error at `state[k] = p[k]`:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ activeRequests: number; test: boolean; }'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ activeRequests: number; test: boolean; }'
```

Looks like `k` has `string` type.
There are some of my attempts:

```
Object.keys(p).forEach((k: stateKeys) => state[k].push(p[k]))
Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"activeRequests" | "test"'`.
```

```
Object.keys(p).forEach(k => (state[k as stateKeys] = p[k])
Error: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'`
```

```
(Object.keys(p) as stateKeys[]).forEach(k => (state[k] = p[k]))
Error: Type 'number | boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that cleanly without generics. Plus you are trying to assign a partially undefined value to a type that doesn't allow undefined. So you need to handle that scenario. Here's a potential solution:

```
var t = function<TState>(state: TState, p: Partial<TState>) {
    let keys = Object.keys(p) as (keyof TState)[];
    for (let key of keys) {
        state[key] = p[key] ?? state[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because you are trying to assing object like this:

```
{
  activeRequests: number | boolean | undefined, 
  test: number | boolean | undefined
}
```

to:

```
{
  activeRequests: number, 
  test: boolean,
}
```

because of the partial and stateKeys part.

Solution is simple like that:

```
const set = (state: state, p: pState) => ({...state, ...p})
```

Comment: I added solution to main answer

Comment: Thank you for your example of solution, but this will create new object. I'd really like to mutate existing `state`. Is there no way to make this work my way?

Comment: You would need to add if statement working as type guards for typescript:

`const set = (state: state, p: pState): void => {
    Object.keys(p).forEach(k => {
      if (k === 'activeRequests') {
        const a = p[k];
        if (a) {
          state[k] = a;
        }
      }
    })
}`